# For an open set $A$ and a relatively closed subset $B$ of $A$, $B$ is closed if $\partial A \cap \partial B = \varnothing$

Tags: general-topology

I am going to show the following:

> For an open set $A$ and a relatively closed subset $B$ of $A$, $B$ is
> closed if $\partial A \cap \partial B = \varnothing$.

**Proof**:
There is a closed set $C$ s.t. $B = C \cap A$. Let $x$ be a limit point of $B$. Since $B \subseteq C$ and $C$ is closed, $x \in C$. Suppose that $x \notin B$ aiming for contradiction.

1. If $x \in \partial A$, $x \notin \partial B$; thus, $x \notin \bar{B}$, and this yields a contradiction because $x$ is a limit point of $B$.
2. If $x \notin \partial A$, from $x \in C \setminus (C \cap A) = C \setminus A$, $x \notin \bar{A}$. But $\bar{B} \subseteq \bar{A}$ and $x \notin \bar{B}$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, we conclude that $x \in B$, i.e., $B$ is closed.

But I think this is a bit verbose, and I am looking for simpler proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $B$ us closed in $A$ we have that $B = \bar B_{A}=\bar B \cap A$.

In addition $B \subseteq \bar A$ and thus because $\bar A$ is closed we have that $\bar B\subseteq \bar A$.

also as $A$ is an open set, we have that $Int(A) = A$ and thus $\partial A = \bar A \setminus Int(A) = \bar A \setminus A $ thus $\partial A \cap A = \emptyset$ so we have $B \cap \partial A = \emptyset$ as $B \subseteq A$

And now

$\bar B = \bar B \cap \bar A = (B \cup \partial B)\cap(A \cup \partial A)=(B \cap A) \cup (B \cap \partial A) \cup (\partial B \cap A) \cup (\partial B \cap \partial A)= (B \cap A) \cup (\partial B \cap A)=(B \cup \partial B) \cap A=\bar B \cap A= \bar B_{A} = B $

And thus B is closed